# Compare Cell formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I´ve developed a small macro on Excel using VBA, which compares the information on column C and copies the formating information contained on column F on sheet(3).

The code is working well, however, I´m trying to optimize it. I would like to avoid copying the formating when a given cell already contains the intended formating. Something like:

```
If Range("C7").Offset(i, 0).***FORMATING*** = Sheets(3).Range("F7").Offset(j, 0).***FORMATING*** Then
```

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to identify the attribute that defines the formatting of a cell.

Please see below the current code I have:

```
Sub Contract()

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, Lastrow As Integer, Lastrow2 As Integer

        Sheets(1).Activate ' activa a sheet(1)

        Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row 
        Lastrow2 = Sheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 0 To Lastrow - Range("c7").Row

            For j = 0 To Lastrow2 - Range("F7").Row

                If Range("C7").Offset(i, 0).Value = Sheets(3).Range("F7").Offset(j, 0).Value Then

                        Sheets(3).Range("F7").Offset(j, 0).Copy
                        Range("C7").Offset(i, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

                 Exit For

                End If  

           Next j

        Next i

    End Sub
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: There are many types of formatting - do you have one thing in mind?

Comment: Hi Thank you for the comment. I wish to compare the full formatting of the cell. Font, font color, fill color etc